# Warning message: step size truncated due to divergence (JOP)

Tags: r, optimization

my goal is to find a setting of controllable machine parameters that brings the mean of multiple responses on target while simultaneously minimizing the variance, therefore i found the very interesting R package called JOP, which stands for Joint Optimization of Multiple Responses.

I have been trying to implement it in my data, but i get the warning message:

> Error: Model building failed for Y1
>   Check the distribution assumption or the link function Warning message: step size truncated due to divergence

and i just cannot find the reason why (it is actually working with small dataset subset as for example 100 rows) and i would like to make it work...i am not very fit in the field of data analytics, therefore any hint will be very helpfull. Below is a sample of my data, as well as the code using JOP package:

**datax**

```
datax <- structure(list(X1 = c(969L, 987L, 987L, 993L, 956L, 998L, 966L, 
950L, 996L, 1004L, 955L, 980L, 974L, 955L, 966L, 978L, 977L, 
984L, 972L, 989L, 974L, 986L, 953L, 974L, 977L, 989L, 1004L, 
996L, 971L, 969L, 996L, 981L, 981L, 951L, 975L, 996L, 992L, 980L, 
987L, 1000L, 985L, 1001L, 978L, 961L, 987L, 1003L, 974L, 982L, 
993L, 991L, 998L, 955L, 980L, 950L, 961L, 974L, 988L, 987L, 986L, 
962L, 976L, 970L, 1014L, 956L, 960L, 972L, 971L, 972L, 954L, 
976L, 973L, 997L, 995L, 982L, 960L, 965L, 1001L, 1004L, 989L, 
912L, 954L, 998L, 990L, 983L, 981L, 982L, 998L, 988L, 970L, 976L, 
1008L, 967L, 983L, 966L, 1017L, 991L, 972L, 963L, 982L, 1006L, 
996L, 986L, 963L, 1015L, 990L, 997L, 962L, 978L, 988L, 964L, 
976L, 979L, 979L, 984L, 981L, 980L, 964L, 975L, 961L, 991L, 1032L, 
965L, 1000L, 997L, 959L, 992L, 966L, 948L, 999L, 971L, 997L, 
988L, 948L, 995L, 975L, 961L, 1001L, 962L, 971L, 995L, 998L, 
996L, 988L, 980L, 1005L, 968L, 983L, 992L, 1013L, 1000L, 992L, 
1010L, 987L, 980L, 941L, 991L, 991L, 961L, 987L, 982L, 972L, 
959L, 980L, 996L, 1004L, 959L, 1001L, 991L, 976L, 981L, 969L, 
962L, 991L, 972L, 985L, 970L, 983L, 948L, 1017L, 1025L, 974L, 
989L, 1004L, 994L, 977L, 987L, 1011L, 960L, 984L, 995L, 1006L, 
987L, 1022L, 1000L, 1006L, 961L, 974L, 946L, 996L, 993L, 962L, 
973L, 958L, 953L, 979L, 958L, 1000L, 1005L, 995L, 959L, 947L, 
978L, 982L, 1010L, 965L, 981L, 993L, 954L, 966L, 957L, 992L, 
962L, 1003L, 997L, 959L, 970L, 994L, 991L, 999L, 977L, 988L, 
952L, 943L, 948L, 992L, 960L, 967L, 965L, 960L, 1010L, 978L, 
1002L, 1005L, 1001L, 990L, 952L, 943L, 965L, 1013L, 999L, 1002L, 
966L, 1002L, 958L, 1003L, 996L, 947L, 963L, 979L, 970L, 963L, 
965L, 981L, 966L, 994L, 957L, 980L, 987L, 987L, 936L, 977L, 964L, 
988L, 985L, 1000L, 987L, 975L, 990L, 965L, 955L, 964L, 947L, 
981L, 1002L, 950L, 991L, 1015L, 975L, 980L, 975L, 988L, 986L, 
967L, 986L, 997L, 973L, 953L, 957L, 993L, 950L, 926L, 961L, 979L, 
946L, 825L, 959L, 967L, 963L, 966L, 963L, 963L, 961L, 1005L, 
948L, 989L, 999L, 1002L, 972L, 986L, 888L, 953L, 959L, 976L, 
963L, 967L, 967L, 972L, 982L, 964L, 983L, 1000L, 974L, 1001L, 
974L, 997L, 1005L, 979L, 987L, 964L, 966L, 984L, 990L, 995L, 
961L, 993L, 984L, 1003L, 978L, 966L, 1008L, 961L, 971L, 963L, 
975L, 919L, 967L, 1000L, 974L, 969L, 957L, 967L, 970L, 948L, 
995L, 948L, 987L, 983L, 996L, 1017L, 1038L, 966L, 1022L, 977L, 
1000L, 987L, 979L, 986L, 992L, 990L, 1025L, 956L, 995L, 987L, 
1001L, 982L, 983L, 991L, 999L, 1007L, 984L, 980L, 991L, 977L, 
961L, 952L, 987L, 1013L, 984L, 968L, 991L, 994L, 958L, 985L, 
1000L, 962L, 1015L, 962L, 977L, 986L, 967L, 950L, 999L, 1004L, 
955L, 1010L, 1025L, 976L, 948L, 958L, 930L, 958L, 968L, 1009L, 
970L, 973L, 965L, 990L, 988L, 958L, 969L, 982L, 970L, 970L, 947L, 
975L, 991L, 986L, 975L, 953L, 1001L, 998L, 1008L, 990L, 989L, 
967L, 970L, 988L, 970L, 957L, 961L, 996L, 970L, 971L, 999L, 958L, 
825L, 966L, 962L, 969L, 970L, 965L, 988L, 1017L, 1008L, 975L, 
976L, 988L, 1006L, 957L, 992L, 967L, 969L, 963L, 958L, 987L, 
971L, 1000L, 978L, 965L, 959L, 996L, 951L, 971L, 976L, 946L, 
979L, 960L, 996L, 970L, 961L, 980L, 982L, 1001L, 997L, 901L, 
960L, 995L, 965L, 999L, 958L), X2 = c(3148, 2084, 1860, 2707, 
2403, 2385, 3388, 1257, 1197, 1748, 2507, 1698, 1144, 1514, 2775, 
2175, 1668, 2365, 2857, 3173, 1426, 1903, 1838, 3036, 1313, 1293, 
2324, 2237, 1608, 2631, 1152, 2214, 2743, 2437, 2559, 2060, 1434, 
1158, 2197, 3373, 2482, 1277, 1315, 2961, 1509, 2627, 1695, 2180, 
1765, 1591, 1600.5, 1556, 2304, 1694, 1347, 2664, 2025, 2701, 
1255, 1590, 3822, 1319, 1923, 1698, 3398, 2751, 1881, 3324, 2223, 
1999, 2274, 1944, 2845.5, 1999, 3059, 1911, 2342, 1408, 2782, 
1703, 2413.5, 1170, 2715, 2238, 1411, 1601, 2266, 1937, 2783, 
1813, 2667, 2126, 1999, 2961, 1792, 1746, 2572, 2465, 1793, 1936, 
1159, 2240, 3007, 984, 2577, 6726, 2180, 1367, 2360, 2558, 1797, 
3066, 2701, 2155, 1823, 2326, 1254, 2665, 1957, 1765, 2427, 1906, 
1494, 2280, 1360, 1335, 3247, 1466, 2342, 2247, 2404, 1159, 1158, 
1637, 1405, 2728, 2404, 3386, 1475, 2036, 1790, 2107, 1775, 1378, 
1936, 1474, 2202, 2103, 1527, 2726, 2446, 1867, 1403, 2325, 1224, 
2539, 1801, 1240, 1396, 1566, 2196, 2257, 1554, 3772, 2644, 1705, 
2745, 2715, 2920, 1443, 3007, 1703, 2921, 1964, 2018, 1185, 1360, 
1581, 2638, 2499, 1913, 2030, 2641, 1347, 2567, 1509, 2355, 2962, 
2472, 2419, 3373, 1454, 3373, 2075, 3664, 2442, 1913, 2887, 2531, 
1653, 2211, 2388, 3032, 2540, 1667, 3124, 1352, 1636, 2152, 1187, 
3477, 1788, 3533, 1134, 2541, 2268, 2576.5, 2062, 2563, 3072, 
2150, 3386, 2784, 1375, 1115, 2932, 2978, 3066, 2682, 3792, 3408, 
2192, 1466, 1825, 2711, 3212, 3556, 1451.5, 2406, 1906, 2380, 
1242, 2571, 2547, 1652, 1181, 952, 2646, 2020, 2067, 2413, 3247, 
2413, 1950, 2667, 2413, 2610, 1425, 3624, 1180, 2549, 1906, 1235, 
1913, 1432, 1662, 1583, 1923, 1988, 1254, 1397, 2494, 2612, 2444, 
1408, 1815, 1510, 1601, 1911, 2231, 1833, 3477, 2411, 1134, 1135, 
1485, 2191, 1109, 1075, 1394, 2614, 1871, 3796, 2497, 2383, 1152, 
1945, 1890, 2531, 1135, 1742, 2933, 2214, 2887, 2376, 1461, 1952, 
2138, 1151, 2465, 3557, 3288, 3486, 2064, 1293, 1997, 2784, 3184, 
1985, 2325, 3761, 2317, 2755, 2761, 1772, 1772, 3690, 3040, 3143, 
1404, 1383, 1169, 1617, 2375, 2052, 3004, 3245, 2451, 1333, 2465, 
2030, 2612, 3030, 2495, 1625, 1385, 1733, 4586, 2465, 2105, 2864, 
4957, 3263, 3538, 2609, 1152, 2238, 1299, 2337, 1853, 1821, 1551, 
963, 1298, 2679, 1403, 3359, 2299, 3042, 2776, 2641, 1824, 1273, 
1556, 1403, 1619, 2078, 1149, 1137, 2499, 1425, 1999, 1653, 1895, 
1722, 1893, 1643, 2075, 3289, 2673, 1614, 1866, 2884, 2810, 2192, 
2433, 1912, 1763, 1181, 3167, 1241, 1425, 1579, 1514, 2425, 1865, 
2156, 2464, 4542, 2475, 1135, 1369, 2241, 1662.5, 1134, 3567, 
3435, 1908, 2562, 2963, 2901, 1886, 2731, 1769, 2759, 2808, 2146, 
1334, 1234, 3329, 3021, 1579, 2238, 2231, 1632, 1022, 969, 2255, 
1691, 2491, 1759, 1491, 2644, 2009, 3557, 3007, 3408, 1617, 2783, 
2810, 1661, 2961, 1982, 1142, 1662.5, 2377, 2493, 3386, 2477, 
2349, 3319, 1510, 2776, 1223, 2532, 1673, 3257, 2218, 2783, 1063, 
1965, 1832, 2549, 3398, 2316, 1094, 1344, 1456, 2455, 1862, 2633, 
1524, 2961, 2091, 3357, 2526, 2406, 2297, 1272, 1304, 971, 2799, 
2404, 2179, 3032, 3098, 2651, 2352, 3187, 2222), X3 = c(117, 
125, 146, 137, 170, 185, 130, 92, 210, 242, 128, 162, 224, 153, 
142, 134, 169, 138, 113, 100, 209, 150, 160, 109, 188, 216, 167, 
118, 193, 139, 236, 159, 133, 131, 128, 127, 111, 92, 147, 107, 
95, 214, 196, 96, 150, 131, 172, 163, 198, 184, 155.5, 177, 131, 
208, 199, 143, 175, 124, 194, 214, 112, 212, 65, 143, 123, 143, 
188, 107, 162, 152, 154, 146, 136, 152, 149, 166, 118, 172, 116, 
180, 143, 228, 115, 175, 177, 200.5, 145, 96, 127, 166, 102, 
148, 152, 96, 104, 184, 150, 152, 133, 149, 245, 106, 200, 230, 
129, 109, 157, 204, 93, 139, 134, 151, 147, 153, 174, 150, 197, 
143, 155, 198, 108, 134, 132, 132, 218, 200, 157, 230, 144, 160, 
175, 195, 269, 196, 141, 142, 175, 133, 196, 168, 181, 119, 204, 
207, 149, 219, 169, 159, 194, 144, 136, 204, 139, 150, 135, 153, 
176, 198, 233, 191, 162, 196, 181, 108, 100, 122, 133, 115, 97, 
140, 145, 185, 125, 174, 149, 179, 218, 179, 57, 111, 173, 177, 
138, 134, 127, 150, 138, 104, 146, 140, 107, 206, 107, 185, 100, 
104, 173, 107, 171, 188, 147, 154, 108, 188, 201, 149, 218, 211, 
96, 292, 147, 172, 123, 207, 146, 140, 137, 223, 182, 124, 46, 
133, 140, 207, 279, 127, 136, 151, 100, 99, 132, 174, 230, 149, 
170, 135, 113, 238.5, 134, 52, 154, 190, 130, 140, 185, 255, 
230, 174, 143, 150, 117, 157, 117, 253, 102, 117, 133, 232, 99, 
156, 161, 134, 236, 196, 239, 202, 175, 214, 151, 233, 227, 97, 
136, 94, 172, 157, 145, 230, 166, 130, 233, 147, 144, 190, 97, 
127.5, 143, 182, 254, 183, 185, 168, 99, 115.5, 155, 228, 123, 
157, 171, 97, 106, 127, 159, 107, 111, 192, 149, 191, 239, 152, 
113, 147, 99, 165, 216, 138, 140, 56, 125, 112, 95, 137, 146, 
116, 132, 132, 64, 133, 129, 201, 115, 235, 164, 150, 195, 25, 
140, 140, 149, 152, 184, 124, 96, 116, 167, 218, 218, 61, 152, 
124, 142, 102, 141, 114, 146, 228, 163, 205, 135, 120, 190, 213, 
227, 185, 118, 139, 112, 128, 107, 106, 150, 232, 201, 171, 139, 
202, 147, 208, 217, 111, 185, 197, 188, 126, 181, 174, 182, 185, 
108, 102, 170, 193, 141, 106, 174, 138, 167, 183, 255, 87, 210, 
185, 184, 193, 121, 149, 109, 150, 56, 123, 97, 196, 167, 200, 
207, 108, 106, 162, 171, 97, 130, 163, 102, 126, 148, 131, 153, 
213, 217, 120, 103, 184, 159, 130, 198, 225, 234, 163, 193, 151, 
233, 251, 100, 142, 113, 145, 132, 204, 127, 106, 143, 96, 183, 
187, 200, 111, 150, 133, 158, 99, 127, 191, 106, 212, 171, 206, 
127, 164, 127, 215, 200, 233, 161, 123, 151, 242, 208, 245, 110, 
150, 98, 207, 96, 157, 89, 137, 134, 166, 187, 245, 241, 142, 
175, 192, 108, 124, 141, 134, 136, 133)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", 
"X3"), row.names = c(NA, -500L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

**datay**

```
datay <- structure(list(Y1 = c(5.41666666666667, 5.5, 5.33333333333333, 
5.425, 5.31666666666667, 5.36833333333333, 5.34166666666667, 
5.38333333333333, 5.41666666666667, 5.42666666666666, 5.35, 5.4, 
5.275, 5.43333333333333, 5.45, 5.34, 5.38, 5.36666666666667, 
5.3, 5.45, 5.275, 5.26666666666667, 5.45, 5.34166666666667, 5.36666666666667, 
5.38333333333333, 5.34666666666667, 5.42777777777778, 5.44166666666666, 
5.3, 5.36666666666667, 5.41666666666667, 5.45, 5.41666666666667, 
5.33333333333333, 5.53333333333333, 5.38333333333333, 5.41666666666667, 
5.3, 5.41666666666667, 5.38333333333333, 5.5, 5.35, 5.3, 5.53333333333333, 
5.38333333333333, 5.425, 5.3, 5.36666666666667, 5.45, 5.39444444444444, 
5.44166666666666, 5.48333333333333, 5.4, 5.415, 5.425, 5.38333333333333, 
5.4, 5.26666666666667, 5.34, 5.4, 5.41666666666667, 5.4, 5.31666666666667, 
5.34166666666667, 5.45, 5.38333333333333, 5.48333333333333, 5.38333333333333, 
5.41666666666667, 5.38333333333333, 5.38333333333333, 5.375, 
5.41666666666667, 5.45, 5.27142857142857, 5.34, 5.41666666666667, 
5.2, 5.31666666666667, 5.28, 5.5, 5.46666666666667, 5.385, 5.43333333333333, 
5.54, 5.5, 5.2, 5.33333333333333, 5.27142857142857, 5.5, 5.4, 
5.41666666666667, 5.3, 5.38333333333333, 5.425, 5.48333333333333, 
5.31666666666666, 5.35, 5.48333333333333, 5.4, 5.33333333333333, 
5.38333333333333, 5.43333333333333, 5.46666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 
5.39166666666667, 5.45, 5.41666666666667, 5.30833333333333, 5.38, 
5.55, 5.43333333333333, 5.38333333333333, 5.41666666666667, 5.36666666666667, 
5.4, 5.425, 5.39166666666667, 5.36666666666667, 5, 5.33333333333333, 
5.39444444444444, 5.51666666666667, 5.4, 5.4, 5.36666666666667, 
5.25, 5.5, 5.38333333333333, 5.385, 5.43333333333333, 5.4, 5.31666666666667, 
5.34, 5.48333333333333, 5.385, 5.31666666666666, 5.41666666666667, 
5.38777777777778, 5.33333333333333, 5.38333333333333, 5.38333333333333, 
5.39166666666666, 5.48333333333333, 5.41666666666667, 5.36666666666667, 
5.5, 5.43333333333333, 5.46666666666667, 5.36666666666667, 5, 
5.25, 5.36666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 5.41666666666667, 5.46666666666667, 
5.35, 5.44166666666666, 5.48333333333333, 5.4, 5.3, 5.51666666666667, 
5.4, 5.34, 5.28333333333333, 5.46666666666667, 5.46666666666667, 
5.31666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 5.38333333333333, 5.54, 5.36666666666667, 
5.41666666666667, 5.45, 5.38333333333333, 5.4, 5.41666666666667, 
5.38333333333333, 5, 5.26666666666667, 5.36666666666667, 5.38333333333333, 
5.43333333333333, 5.38333333333333, 5.53333333333333, 5.48333333333333, 
5.33333333333333, 5.41666666666667, 5.43333333333333, 5.41666666666667, 
5.38333333333333, 5.41666666666667, 5.42666666666666, 5.19, 5.45, 
5.26666666666667, 5.38333333333333, 5.44, 5.34285714285715, 5.38333333333333, 
5.42, 5.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 5.41666666666667, 5.39166666666667, 
5.38777777777778, 5.42666666666666, 5.38333333333333, 5.4, 5.45, 
5.41666666666667, 5.40833333333333, 5.43333333333333, 5.23333333333333, 
5.38166666666666, 5.425, 5.28333333333333, 5.38333333333333, 
5.38333333333333, 5.36666666666667, 5.31666666666666, 5.38888888888889, 
5.35, 5.4, 5.35, 5.36666666666667, 5.55, 5.43333333333333, 5.34166666666667, 
5.46666666666667, 5.28333333333333, 5.25, 5.45, 5.45, 5.45, 5.34166666666667, 
5.34, 5.27142857142857, 5.36666666666667, 5.425, 5.25, 5.46666666666667, 
5.51666666666667, 5.45, 5.38333333333333, 5.38333333333333, 5.45, 
5.45, 5.46666666666667, 5.41666666666667, 5.36666666666667, 5.41666666666667, 
5.28333333333333, 5.5, 5.41666666666667, 5.35, 5.38333333333333, 
5.4, 5.33333333333333, 5.23333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 5.44166666666667, 
5.43333333333333, 5.44166666666666, 5.43333333333333, 5.39444444444444, 
5.54166666666667, 5.4, 5.38333333333333, 5.34166666666667, 5.41666666666667, 
5.38, 5.43333333333333, 5.41666666666667, 5.45, 5.38333333333333, 
5.46666666666667, 5.27142857142857, 5.26666666666667, 5.4, 5.45, 
5.33888888888889, 5.425, 5.36666666666667, 5.38333333333333, 
5.37777777777778, 5.44166666666667, 5.45, 5.4, 5.36833333333333, 
5.36666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 5.48333333333333, 5.35, 5.4, 
5.41666666666667, 5.41666666666667, 5.44, 5.36666666666667, 5.43333333333333, 
5.35, 5.41666666666667, 5.38333333333333, 5.34, 5.43333333333333, 
5.34, 5.48333333333333, 5.48333333333333, 5.31666666666666, 5.34166666666667, 
5.39333333333333, 5.35, 5.41666666666667, 5.38333333333333, 5.41666666666667, 
5.38888888888889, 5.36666666666667, 5.38166666666666, 5.34, 5.29166666666666, 
5.38, 5.35, 5.3, 5.36666666666667, 5.36666666666667, 5.41666666666667, 
5.41666666666667, 5.45, 5.48333333333333, 5.51666666666667, 5.275, 
5.39444444444444, 5.425, 5.43333333333333, 5.325, 5.55, 5.51666666666667, 
5.325, 5.31666666666666, 5.41666666666667, 5.46666666666667, 
5.4, 5.41666666666667, 5.36666666666667, 5.4, 5.36666666666667, 
5.35, 5.31666666666666, 5.46666666666667, 5.36666666666667, 5.35, 
5.3, 5.45, 5.38333333333333, 5.4, 5.385, 5.39166666666666, 5.33333333333333, 
5.31666666666667, 5.45, 5.30833333333333, 5.33333333333333, 5.425, 
5.36, 5.25, 5.36666666666667, 5.36666666666667, 5.175, 5, 5.35, 
5.34666666666667, 5.45, 5.425, 5.25, 5.42, 5.38333333333333, 
5.25, 5.25, 5, 5.44166666666666, 5.385, 5.34285714285715, 5.48, 
5.4, 5.45, 5.38333333333333, 5.42666666666666, 5.42777777777778, 
5.45, 5.53333333333333, 5.4, 5.48333333333333, 5.36666666666667, 
5.28333333333333, 5.53333333333333, 5.41666666666667, 5.38333333333333, 
5.38333333333333, 5.43333333333334, 5.43333333333333, 5.44166666666666, 
5.41666666666667, 5.5, 5.35, 5.45, 5.41666666666667, 5.38333333333333, 
5.5, 5.4, 5.36666666666667, 5.5, 5.42777777777778, 5.43333333333333, 
5.43333333333333, 5, 5.41666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 5.45, 
5.3, 5.39166666666667, 5.25, 5.38333333333333, 5.43333333333333, 
5.45, 5.34166666666667, 5.36666666666667, 5.48333333333333, 5.415, 
5.35, 5.4, 5.41666666666667, 5.36666666666667, 5.26666666666667, 
5.41666666666667, 5.43333333333333, 5.53333333333333, 5.36666666666667, 
5.43333333333334, 5.39222222222222, 5, 5, 5.34, 5.43333333333333, 
5.34166666666667, 5.38333333333333, 5.46666666666667, 5.25, 5.33333333333333, 
5.36666666666667, 5.325, 5.3, 5.4, 5.33333333333333, 5.43333333333333, 
5.34, 5.51666666666667, 5.31666666666666, 5.39166666666666, 5.26666666666667, 
5.36666666666667, 5.48333333333333, 5, 5.43333333333333, 5.42, 
5.53333333333333, 5.46666666666667, 5.38333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 
5.4, 5.38333333333333, 5.4, 5.23333333333333, 5.34166666666667, 
5.43333333333334, 5.46666666666667, 5.45, 5.38333333333333, 5.35833333333334, 
5.36666666666667, 5.43333333333333, 5.415, 5.3, 5.36666666666667, 
5.26666666666667, 5.35, 5.27142857142857, 5.38333333333333, 5.4, 
5.48333333333333, 5.325, 5.36666666666667, 5.385, 5.43333333333333, 
5.33333333333333, 5.45, 5.35, 5.23333333333333, 5.375, 5.45), 
    Y2 = c(6.01666666666667, 6, 6, 6.03333333333333, 6, 6, 6, 
    6.03333333333333, 6, 6.08166666666667, 6, 6, 6.01666666666666, 
    6.03333333333333, 6.05, 6, 6.1, 6, 6.33333333333333, 6, 6.01666666666666, 
    6, 6, 6.06666666666667, 6.025, 6.1, 6.19777777777778, 6.2, 
    6.13333333333333, 6, 6, 6.01666666666667, 6, 6, 6.43333333333333, 
    6, 6.21666666666667, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.01666666666667, 
    6, 6, 6.13333333333333, 6, 6, 6.01666666666666, 6, 6, 6.3, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.06666666666667, 6, 6.05, 6, 6.03333333333333, 
    6.38333333333333, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.03333333333333, 
    6.01666666666666, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.04, 6.03333333333333, 6, 
    6.19166666666667, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.03333333333333, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.025, 6, 6, 6.10833333333334, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.025, 6.01666666666667, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.03333333333333, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.4, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6.11, 6, 6, 6, 6.025, 6, 6, 6.01666666666667, 6.03333333333333, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.08333333333333, 
    6, 6, 6, 6.03333333333333, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.04, 6.05, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.08333333333333, 6, 6.13333333333333, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.1, 6, 6.08166666666667, 6, 6, 6, 6.3, 
    6, 6.01428571428571, 6, 6.00833333333333, 6.05, 6, 6, 6.03333333333333, 
    6.11, 6.08166666666667, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.03333333333333, 
    6.00833333333333, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.06666666666667, 
    6.03333333333333, 6.00833333333333, 6, 6, 6.01666666666667, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.00833333333333, 
    6, 6, 6.26666666666667, 6, 6, 6.01666666666667, 6, 6, 6, 
    6.09166666666667, 6, 6.15, 6, 6, 6, 6.38333333333333, 6, 
    6.06666666666667, 6.08, 6, 6, 6, 6.21666666666667, 6, 6, 
    6.13333333333333, 6.3, 6, 6.08333333333333, 6, 6, 6.21666666666667, 
    6.04166666666666, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.3, 6.03333333333333, 
    6.03333333333333, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.01666666666667, 6.3, 6, 6.09166666666667, 
    6.4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.09166666666667, 
    6, 6, 6.33333333333333, 6.2, 6.2, 6.16666666666667, 6.01666666666667, 
    6, 6, 6, 6.01666666666666, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.04166666666666, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6.06666666666667, 6.03333333333333, 6, 6.13333333333333, 
    6, 6, 6.025, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.3, 6, 6.025, 6.19166666666667, 
    6.03333333333333, 6, 6.10833333333334, 6.06666666666667, 
    6, 6, 6, 6.11666666666667, 6.13333333333333, 6, 6, 6.26666666666667, 
    6.19777777777778, 6, 6, 6, 6.00833333333333, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6.13333333333333, 6, 6.01428571428571, 6, 6, 6.03333333333333, 
    6.21666666666667, 6.08166666666667, 6.06666666666667, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6.00833333333333, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.13333333333333, 
    6, 6, 6.08333333333333, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.06666666666667, 
    6.15, 6, 6, 6.16666666666667, 6, 6, 6.03333333333333, 6.03333333333333, 
    6.05833333333334, 6.13333333333333, 6.03333333333333, 6.05, 
    6, 6.01666666666667, 6, 6.01666666666666, 6, 6, 6, 6.01666666666667, 
    6.13333333333333, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.15, 6, 6, 6, 6.01666666666667, 
    6, 6, 6.03333333333333, 6.1, 6.19166666666667, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6.15, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.08333333333333, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.00833333333333, 
    6, 6.03333333333333, 6.13333333333333, 6.19166666666667, 
    6, 6, 6.3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.05, 6.01666666666666, 6.13333333333333, 
    6, 6.01666666666666, 6, 6.01666666666667, 6.03333333333333, 
    6.05, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6.09166666666667, 6, 6, 6, 6.05, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6.03333333333333), Y3 = c(7.3, 7.31666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 
    7.31666666666667, 7.3, 7.345, 7.34166666666667, 7.35, 7.31666666666667, 
    7.41, 7.36666666666667, 7.34, 7.375, 7.375, 7.35, 7.3, 7.4, 
    7.33333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 7.36666666666667, 7.375, 
    7.4, 7.25, 7.28333333333333, 7.39166666666666, 7.36666666666667, 
    7.34555555555556, 7.38333333333333, 7.38333333333333, 7.3, 
    7.31666666666667, 7.38333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 7.3, 
    7.26666666666667, 7.21666666666667, 7.31666666666667, 7.41666666666667, 
    7.33333333333333, 7.4, 7.38333333333333, 7.2, 7.31666666666667, 
    7.28333333333333, 7.21666666666667, 7.38333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 
    7.33333333333333, 7.38333333333333, 7.36666666666667, 7.35833333333333, 
    7.38333333333333, 7.38333333333333, 7.31666666666667, 7.39, 
    7.375, 7.46666666666667, 7.3, 7.36666666666667, 7.36, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.4, 7.36666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 7.34166666666667, 
    7.35, 7.2, 7.36666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.36666666666667, 7.35, 7.40833333333333, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.33333333333333, 7.3, 7.3, 7.2, 7.35, 7.21666666666667, 
    7.35333333333334, 7.23333333333333, 7.4, 7.33833333333333, 
    7.31666666666667, 7.38, 7.36666666666667, 7.35, 7.33333333333333, 
    7.3, 7.31666666666667, 7.4, 7.38333333333333, 7.28333333333333, 
    7.26666666666667, 7.4, 7.36666666666667, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.25, 7.36666666666667, 7.2, 7.33333333333333, 7.4, 7.4, 
    7.4, 7.35, 7.4, 7.4, 7.3, 7.34166666666667, 7.34, 7.23333333333333, 
    7.36666666666667, 7.31666666666667, 7.35, 7.35, 7.36666666666667, 
    7.375, 7.4, 7.38333333333333, 7, 7.4, 7.35833333333333, 7.36666666666667, 
    7.36666666666667, 7.35, 7.36666666666667, 7.31666666666667, 
    7.36666666666667, 7.23333333333333, 7.33833333333333, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.35, 7.35, 7.325, 7.4, 7.33833333333333, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.28333333333333, 7.40833333333333, 7.21666666666667, 7.35833333333334, 
    7.33333333333333, 7.35, 7.36666666666667, 7.4, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.36666666666667, 7.38333333333333, 7.38333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 
    7, 7.43333333333333, 7.35, 7.3, 7.3, 7.33333333333333, 7.4, 
    7.34166666666667, 7.36666666666667, 7.36666666666667, 7.36666666666667, 
    7.36666666666667, 7.3, 7.3, 7.35, 7.4, 7.4, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.4, 7.4, 7.38, 7.41666666666667, 7.4, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.375, 7.36666666666667, 7.28333333333333, 7.38333333333333, 
    7, 7.36666666666667, 7.31666666666667, 7.31666666666667, 
    7.25, 7.4, 7.21666666666667, 7.36666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 
    7.36666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 7.4, 7.36666666666667, 
    7.4, 7.41, 7.2, 7.38333333333333, 7.36666666666667, 7.31666666666667, 
    7.39, 7.25714285714286, 7.36666666666667, 7.34666666666667, 
    7.36666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 7.35, 7.36666666666667, 
    7.40833333333333, 7.41, 7.36666666666667, 7.35, 7.33333333333333, 
    7.4, 7.41666666666667, 7.4, 7.38333333333333, 7.32, 7.31666666666667, 
    7.4, 7.36666666666667, 7.38333333333333, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.38333333333333, 7.36666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 7.35, 
    7.2, 7.38333333333333, 7.23333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 
    7.28333333333333, 7.35833333333333, 7.4, 7.31666666666667, 
    7.35, 7.28333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 7.34166666666667, 
    7.36, 7.3, 7.38333333333333, 7.375, 7.43333333333333, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.3, 7.33333333333333, 7.2, 7.2, 7.38333333333333, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.2, 7.35, 7.36666666666667, 7.35, 7.4, 7.31666666666667, 
    7.35, 7.36666666666667, 7.2, 7.3, 7.31666666666667, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.4, 7.2, 7.34166666666667, 7.34166666666667, 7.23333333333333, 
    7.35833333333333, 7.2, 7.34, 7.33333333333333, 7.35833333333333, 
    7.35, 7.38, 7.33333333333333, 7.2, 7.36666666666667, 7.31666666666667, 
    7.33333333333333, 7.3, 7.31666666666667, 7.4, 7.33333333333333, 
    7.24166666666667, 7.4, 7.35, 7.31666666666667, 7.34166666666667, 
    7.2, 7.2, 7.35, 7.345, 7.31666666666667, 7.23333333333333, 
    7.33333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 7.4, 7.21666666666667, 
    7.21666666666667, 7.39, 7.35, 7.33333333333333, 7.2, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.31666666666667, 7.3, 7.34166666666667, 7.325, 7.4, 7.21666666666667, 
    7.38333333333333, 7.34166666666667, 7.38333333333333, 7.33333333333334, 
    7.28333333333333, 7.36666666666667, 7.31666666666667, 7.36666666666667, 
    7.33333333333333, 7.32, 7.3, 7.35, 7.34, 7.35, 7.33333333333333, 
    7.33333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 7.38333333333333, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.33333333333333, 7.4, 7.43333333333333, 7.375, 7.35833333333333, 
    7.375, 7.2, 7.38333333333333, 7.23333333333333, 7.3, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.38333333333333, 7.36666666666667, 7.4, 7.3, 7.35, 7.23333333333333, 
    7.36666666666667, 7.38333333333333, 7.31666666666667, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.36666666666667, 7.35, 7.31666666666667, 7.3, 7.33333333333333, 
    7.31666666666667, 7.4, 7.33833333333333, 7.35, 7.33333333333333, 
    7.21666666666667, 7.36666666666667, 7.34166666666667, 7.31666666666667, 
    7.4, 7.3, 7.43333333333333, 7.325, 7.38333333333333, 7.2, 
    7, 7.36666666666667, 7.34555555555556, 7.4, 7.4, 7.43333333333333, 
    7.34666666666667, 7.46666666666667, 7.3, 7.3, 7, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.33833333333333, 7.25714285714286, 7.36, 7.35, 7.31666666666667, 
    7.31666666666667, 7.41, 7.38333333333333, 7.35, 7.21666666666667, 
    7.36666666666667, 7.38333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 7.4, 
    7.36666666666667, 7.31666666666667, 7.36666666666667, 7.2, 
    7.4, 7.38333333333333, 7.38333333333333, 7.36666666666667, 
    7.23333333333333, 7.31666666666667, 7.38333333333333, 7.3, 
    7.31666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 7.4, 7.35, 7.23333333333333, 
    7.38333333333333, 7.23333333333333, 7.4, 7, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.3, 7.33333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 7.36666666666667, 
    7.375, 7.38333333333333, 7.375, 7.35, 7.34166666666667, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.36666666666667, 7.39, 7.2, 7.35, 7.36666666666667, 7.43333333333333, 
    7.31666666666667, 7.28333333333333, 7.38333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 
    7.35, 7.31666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 7, 7, 7.3, 7.33333333333333, 
    7.34166666666667, 7.4, 7.35833333333333, 7.40833333333333, 
    7.33333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 7.3, 7.28333333333333, 
    7.36666666666667, 7.35, 7.23333333333333, 7.3, 7.3, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.4, 7.33333333333333, 7.36666666666667, 7.36666666666667, 
    7, 7.4, 7.34666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 7.35833333333333, 
    7.38333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 7.36666666666667, 7.38333333333333, 
    7.4, 7.38333333333333, 7.34166666666667, 7.4, 7.21666666666667, 
    7.25, 7.4, 7.39722222222222, 7.36666666666667, 7.3, 7.39, 
    7.28333333333333, 7.43333333333333, 7.21666666666667, 7.35, 
    7.3, 7.4, 7.36666666666667, 7.21666666666667, 7.375, 7.35, 
    7.33833333333333, 7.3, 7.36666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 
    7.33333333333333, 7.38333333333333, 7.40833333333333, 7.31666666666667
    )), .Names = c("Y1", "Y2", "Y3"), row.names = c(NA, -500L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**JOP code**

```
library(JOP)
out1 <- JOP(datax = datax, datay = datay, optreg = "box",solver="gosolnp",joplot = TRUE)
```

Comment: The first failure is in dglm with the following model: `dglm(Y1 ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + I(X3^2) + X1:X2 + X1:X3, 
     ~X1 + X2 + X3, data = cbind(datax, datay), family = stats::gaussian, 
     dlink = "log", method = "reml")`. That specific failure can be solved by removing row 10, but it still fails on modeling `Y1`. It works fine without that column, but I can't explain the specific characteristics of that output that are causing a problem.

Comment: I just cannot figure out neither, why it fails with `Y1`